# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. If $x * a \in H$ for all $a \in H$, does it follow that $x \in H$?

Tags: group-theory

**Edit**: Pardon my tardiness. I had an exam today. Just to clarify, as noted by many members here, I am adding a bit more context to the problem.

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a Group $G$. Then for all $x$ belongs to $G$ and for all $a$ belongs to $H$, $x*a$ belongs to $H$. So, now, do all $x$ belongs to $H$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response to your added information:

Let $x\in G$ and $a\in H$. Then $x*a\in H$.
This means that $x*a=h$ for some $h\in H$.
Multiplying $a^{-1}$ on both sides, we get $x=h*a^{-1}$.
Since $H$ is a subgroup, $a^{-1}\in H$ and hence $x=h*a^{-1}\in H$.

Comment: Thanks. It was so elementary. I wonder how I overlooked it. Perhaps, exam dilemma.

Answer (score 2):

As people have said in the comments, unless you add more hypothesis about how $*$ behaves "outside" $G$, then one cannot conclude anything.

If you want a specific example with $a\notin G$, let $H=\{a,e\}$ with $a\neq e$ and define a binary operation $*$ on $H$ such that $x*y=e$ for every $x,y\in H$. Let $G=\{e\}$.
Then $(G,*)$ is a group, and $x*a\in G$ for all $x\in G$.

Note that $*$ is associative, so $(H,*)$ is a semigroup.

Comment: Added some more information about $a$. Please have a look.